# Настройка поля Журнал изменений в списках в Битрикс 24

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Настроил бизнес процесс, который при изменении любого поля списка вносит информацию о новом значении в нередактируемое поле "История изменений".

Что нужно добавить в БП, чтобы в поле "История изменений" вносилась также информация о старом значении поля. Пример: Изменил статус с "Открыто" на "В работе"?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]